# Averaging and comparing mean values across studies

Tags: meta-analysis

I am having a statistical problem that falls into two parts:

(!) I have several literature reports on studies that have investigated the effect of drug "A" on a particular laboratory parameter. Some articles report the mean and SD values at baseline and treatment end while others report mean and SD intra-individual change between baseline and end of treatment. How can I determine the average change between baseline and treatment end across all studies?

(2) Experiments like those in (1) have been reported not only for drug "A", but also for "B", "C", and "D" (of course, the laboratory measure of interest is always the same). For each drug, I only have some value(s) for average change over time, but there is neither a head-to-head comparison nor an indirect comparison between them. Is there anything more that I can do to compare the effects of the drugs on the lab measure except to present average change and some measure of variability side by side?

Thank you,
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert everything to mean differences with their standard error. If you only have means and sd before and after you will need to impute a value for the correlation coefficient between before and after scores. You may be able to estimate this if any studies have presented their results in both the formats you describe.

With the means and standard errors you can in principle compare the drugs using a meta-regression although as you say these will be indirect comparisons.